# El contenido de un JTextArea no se guarda en un archivo y aun por encima me da excepciones

Tags: java, java-swing, archivo, guardar

Hola buenas noches estoy haciendo un procesador de textos en el que voy escribiendo en un JTextArea y luego tengo un botón "Guardar" en el que al pulsarlo se me abre un diálogo de Windows para guardar y acto seguido al darle aceptar pasa el contenido del JTextArea a un archivo de texto que crea el programa, el problema que tengo es que al darle a Guardar me sale una excepción, antes no me salía pero el programa no me guardaba nada en el archivo, os paso los códigos porque no consigo solucionarlo, saludos.

El código del botón "Guardar":

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Documento de texto (.txt)"); //Filtro de la extensión de archivo a guardar
        final JFileChooser selector = new JFileChooser();   //Creo el selector
        selector.setApproveButtonText("Guardar");       //Botón guardar
        selector.setFileFilter(filter);

        int returnVal = selector.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (returnVal != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            return;
        }

        File archivo = selector.getSelectedFile();
        if (!archivo.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            archivo = new File(archivo.getAbsolutePath() + ".txt");
        }

        BufferedWriter archivo_salida = null;
        try {
            archivo_salida = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
            jTextArea1.write(archivo_salida);       //Traslado el texto del area al archivo
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            if (archivo_salida != null) {
                try {
                    archivo_salida.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```

El frame que tengo contiene solo un JTextArea y un botón Guardar, el main tengo esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Procesador tarea = new Procesador();
    tarea.setVisible(true);
}
```

Estas son las excepciones que me salen:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Extensions must be non-null and not empty
    at javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter.<init>(FileNameExtensionFilter.java:76)
    at picotowriter.Procesador.jButton1ActionPerformed(Procesador.java:83)
    at picotowriter.Procesador.access$000(Procesador.java:19)
    at picotowriter.Procesador$1.actionPerformed(Procesador.java:51)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Atentamente, saludos!

Comment: Como creas el archivo, agregalo a tu pregunta.

Comment: A través del buffer que escribirá lo que haya del JTextArea

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tu error te indica que está pasando:

```
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Documento de texto (.txt)"); //Filtro de la extensión de archivo a guardar
```

Es una función pensada para tener dos parámetros al menos, pues está definida como:

```
FileNameExtensionFilter(String description, String... extensions)
```

donde extensions es un varargs, e internamente se maneja como un arreglo, por ello es que extensions esta en nulo de la manera en que lo pusiste.

Deberías modificar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Documento de texto (.txt)", "txt"); //Filtro de la extensión de archivo a guardar
```

Al respecto puedes leer [la documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html).

Comment: Ah vale era que le faltaba la extensión... fue añadirle ese parámetro y ya me permite guardar y el JTextArea se guarda en el archivo, muchas gracias @Ruslan López

Comment: así es, @DaburaNet1998 si resolví tu problema te recomiendo darle click al botón de la palomita junto a mi respuesta, si te ayudé a resolver flechita arriba junto a mi respuesta; no me pagan ni nada, pero a veces me hacen falta esas endorfinas.

Comment: Disculpa jajaja porque pensé que le había dado el otro día pero ahí lo tiene gran caballero!

Comment: Como la pregunta fue bloqueada en meta (mal ahí admin, si, tú) y ya no es posible dar +1, vengo a dejar mi +1 por acá, ya que me divertí con las referencias. [Solo eso](https://youtu.be/mOhwS3u_QL8)

Answer (score 7):

De acuerdo a el error:

> IllegalArgumentException: Extensions must be non-null and not empty

Al crear tu archivo es importante le definas una extension, asegura en este punto  contenga además del nombre la extensiòn:

```
 FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Documento de texto","txt");
```